# Изумрудно-тенистый — раздельно или через дефис?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, раздельно-дефис

*Похожие воспоминания он вынес из детства: в Корнуолле первое, что бросалось в глаза по утрам, — это сверкание моря, синего, как крыло мотылька; загадочный **изумрудно-тенистый** мир зарослей гуннеры в саду «Треба»; далекие белые паруса, покачивающиеся, как птицы, на шумливых серо-стальных волнах.*
[Р. Гэлбрейт. На службе зла](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=53624&p=47)

Я покрутила-повертела, но так и не смогла определиться.
А как бы вы написали — раздельно или через дефис? Как правильно?

Answer (score 3):

**Изумрудно-тенистый мир зарослей.**

Скорее всего, речь идет **о цвете**: заросли тенистые, но зелень не темного, а изумрудного цвета (возможно, от рассеянных лучей).

**Все оттенки цветов пишутся обычно через дефис.** Слову **изумрудно** сложно стать наречием и писаться раздельно.

Самые близкие значения — это **степень признака и сравнение** (чудно нежный, ослепительно яркий), но и они не подходят.

Конечно, авторы очень изобретательны в отношении таких сочетаний, и можно представить себе авторскую метафору, основанную **на сравнении с изумрудом,** например: *изумрудно сияющие звёзды.* Но и это слово будет скорее писаться через дефис.

Comment: У меня в памяти крутились-вертелись похожие строки. Ваш ответ помог мне вспомнить: дымно-лиственный туман, чёрно-блещущий агат, фиолетно-бледный лист, бледно-лунная игра. К. Д. Бальмонт. Взоры гор. https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/Взоры_гор_(Бальмонт)/1912_(ВТ:Ё) Спасибо!

Comment: К этому обязательно следует добавить, что подобно упомянутым Вами изыскам Бальмонта, "изумрудно-тенистый" является образцом литературного дурновкусия. Персонаж типа Епиходова мог бы вписать подобный оборотец в журнал томной провинциальной барышни.

Comment: @ Michael_1812  А как Вы определяете, что это дурновкусие? Есть какие-то определенные объективные признаки или это Ваше субъективное мнение (ощущение)?

Comment: @Sharon   А Вы прикиньте, какого типа литературный персонаж мог бы исторгнуть из себя такое словечко. И какого склада героиня могла б в ответ умилиться. :)

Comment: @Sharon  Заодно нам повод поразмышлять, отчего томный Бальмонт не оставил по себе такого следа и всплеска, как скажем, Ахматова.  (Oб этом сказал ИБ: "Ахматова учит сдержанности.")

Comment: @ Michael_1812 А если, к примеру,  мне не нравится сдержанность? Яркость красок и чувств - это всегда дурновкусие? И подражание чужим вкусам - это всегда хороший вкус? А вообще-то мне хотелось бы, чтобы Вы дали ответ в такой форме: дурновкусие - это...

Answer (score 2):

- Мир изумрудно-тенистый — мир *(какой?)* изумрудно-тенистый — мир и изумрудный, и тенистый одновременно.
- Мир изумрудно тенистый — мир *(какой?)* тенистый *(как? каким образом? в какой степени?)* изумрудно — «изумрудно» является дополнительной, вторичной характеристикой.

Учитывая, что второй вариант здесь не имеет смысла, используют только первый, если только не требуется какая-то фигура речи на основе необычных аналогий.

Comment: _...фигура речи на основе необычных аналогий._ А что — вполне возможно! Мне вспомнились вот эти строчки: _Оранжевые мамы оранжевым ребятам
Оранжевые песни **оранжево** поют._

Answer (score 2):

> Октябрь серебристо-ореховый.
>
> Блеск заморозков оловянный.
>
> Осенние сумерки Чехова,
>
> Чайковского и Левитана.

Правило, которого я прежде не замечала:

[Имена прилагательные, образованные путем слияния двух основ, пишутся через дефис, если:](http://gramatik.ru/slitnoe-i-defisnoe-napisanie-prilagatelnyh/)

> ...произошли от двух основ и обозначают качество с дополнительным
> оттенком:
>
> *раскатисто-громкий, переливчато-напевный, задорно-звонкий*

Мы учили только это, с [Культуры письменной речи](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.49), это и есть НАШ СЛУЧАЙ:

> Через дефис пишутся ... также индивидуально-авторские образования:
> *честно-голубые глаза, выпукло-серые пуговицы, смугло-волосатые руки.*

Так что ***изумрудно-тенистый мир зарослей гуннеры*** - сугубо-вопиюще индивидуально-авторское образование!